# How can I reduce the time complexity of the given python code?

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

I have this python program which computes the "Square Free Numbers" of a given number. I'm facing problem regarding the time complexity that is I'm getting the error as "Time Limit Exceeded" in an online compiler.

```
number = int(input())
factors = []
perfectSquares = []
count = 0
total_len = 0

# Find All the Factors of the given number
for i in range(1, number):
if number%i == 0:
    factors.append(i)

# Find total number of factors        
total_len = len(factors)

for items in factors:
    for i in range(1,total_len):
  # Eleminate perfect square numbers
    if items == i * i:
        if items == 1:
            factors.remove(items)
            count += 1
        else:
            perfectSquares.append(items)
            factors.remove(items)
            count += 1

# Eleminate factors that are divisible by the perfect squares 
for i in factors:
    for j in perfectSquares:
    if i%j == 0:
        count +=1

# Print Total Square Free numbers
total_len -= count 
print(total_len)
```

How can I reduce the time complexity of this program? That is how can I reduce the for loops so the program gets executed with a smaller time complexity?

Comment: complexity has little to do with the language, and a lot with the algorithm you are using. To reduce the time complexity, you will have to optimize your code and /or change your algorithm.

Comment: For what inputs is this approach too slow?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh `Test case 1: 20` `Test case 2: 72`

Comment: WHat does this code do? Print the number of square-free numbers less than number?

Comment: I was under the impression that a square free number was one for which the unique prime factorization contained any prime at most once.  Is your program supposed to identify unique primes, identify all the unique primes up to a number, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Algorithmic Techniques for Reducing Time Complexity(TC) of a python code.

In order to reduce time complexity of a code, it's very much necessary to reduce the usage of loops whenever and wherever possible.

I'll divide your code's logic part into 5 sections and suggest optimization in each one of them.

#### Section 1 - Declaration of Variables and taking input

```
number = int(input())
factors = []
perfectSquares = []
count = 0
total_len = 0
```

You can easily omit declaration of perfect squares, count and total_length, as they aren't needed, as explained further. This will reduce both Time and Space complexities of your code.

Also, you can use Fast IO, in order to speed up INPUTS and OUTPUTS
This is done by using 'stdin.readline', and 'stdout.write'.

#### Section 2 - Finding All factors

```
for i in range(1, number):
    if number%i == 0:
        factors.append(i)
```

1. Here, you can use List comprehension technique to create the factor list, due to the fact that List comprehension is faster than looping statements.
2. Also, you can just iterate till square root of the Number, instead of looping till number itself, thereby reducing time complexity exponentially.
   Above code section guns down to...

###### After applying '1' hack

```
factors = [for i in range(1, number) if number%i == 0]
```

###### After applying '2' hack - Use from_iterable to store more than 1 value in each iteration in list comprehension

```
factors = list( chain.from_iterable(
  (i, int(number/i)) for i in range(2, int(number**0.5)+1)
    if number%i == 0
  ))
```

#### Section 3 - Eliminating Perfect Squares

```
# Find total number of factors        
total_len = len(factors)

for items in factors:
    for i in range(1,total_len):
  # Eleminate perfect square numbers
    if items == i * i:
        if items == 1:
            factors.remove(items)
            count += 1
        else:
            perfectSquares.append(items)
            factors.remove(items)
            count += 1
```

Actually you can completely omit this part, and just add additional condition to the Section 2, namely ... type(i**0.5) != int, to eliminate those numbers which have integer square roots, hence being perfect squares themselves.
Implement as follows....

```
factors = list( chain.from_iterable(
  (i, int(number/i)) for i in range(2, int(number**0.5)+1)
    if number%i == 0 and type(i**0.5) != int
  ))
```

#### Section 4 - I think this Section isn't needed because Square Free Numbers doesn't have such Restriction

#### Section 5 - Finalizing Count, Printing Count

There's absolutely no need of counter, you can just compute length of factors list, and use it as Count.

### OPTIMISED CODES

#### Way 1 - Little Faster

```
number = int(input())

# Find Factors of the given number
factors = []
for i in range(2, int(number**0.5)+1):
    if number%i == 0 and type(i**0.5) != int:
        factors.extend([i, int(number/i)])

print([1] + factors)
```

#### Way 2 - Optimal Programming - Very Fast

```
from itertools import chain 
from sys import stdin, stdout

number = int(stdin.readline())
factors = list( chain.from_iterable(
  (i, int(number/i)) for i in range(2, int(number**0.5)+1)
    if number%i == 0 and type(i**0.5) != int
  ))

stdout.write(', '.join(map(str, [1] + factors)))
```

Comment: Using sys functions improves the IO operations TC, but keep in mind, unlike print(), write() function doesn't put '\n' at the end of a string by default

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you only need to check `for i in range(1, number/2):`, since `number/2 + 1` and greater cannot be factors.

Second, you can compute the number of perfect squares that could be factors in sublinear time:

```
squares = []
for i in range(1, math.floor(math.sqrt(number/2))):
    squares.append(i**2)
```

Third, you can search for factors and when you find one, check that it is not divisible by a square, and only then add it to the list of factors.

This approach will save you all the time of your `for items in factors` nested loop block, as well as the next block.  I'm not sure if it will definitely be faster, but it is less wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code provided in the answer above but it didn't give me the correct answer. This actually computes the square free list of factors of a number.

```
number = int(input())
factors = [
  i for i in range(2, int(number/2)+1)
    if number%i == 0 and int(int(math.sqrt(i))**2)!=i
]

print([1] + factors)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31468283)